# How to insert DataSet in table with column defined as GENERATED ALWAYS using database-rider?

Tags: postgresql, junit5, dbunit

Trying to insert test_data.xml using DBRider *@DataSet* annotation.

XML contains data like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE dataset SYSTEM "src\main\resources\test_dataset.dtd">
<dataset>
    <groups group_name='SG-83'/>
</dataset>
```

My schema looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE groups
(
    group_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    group_name character varying(256) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL
)
```

Test fails with following trace:

```
Caused by: com.github.database.rider.core.exception.DataBaseSeedingException: Could not initialize dataset: test_data.xml
    at com.github.database.rider.core.dataset.DataSetExecutorImpl.createDataSet(DataSetExecutorImpl.java:141)
    at com.github.database.rider.core.RiderRunner.runBeforeTest(RiderRunner.java:44)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: org.dbunit.DatabaseUnitException: Exception processing table name='groups'
    at org.dbunit.operation.AbstractBatchOperation.execute(AbstractBatchOperation.java:240)
    at org.dbunit.operation.CompositeOperation.execute(CompositeOperation.java:79)
    at com.github.database.rider.core.dataset.DataSetExecutorImpl.createDataSet(DataSetExecutorImpl.java:132)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cannot insert into column "group_id"
  Detail: Column "group_id" is an identity column defined as GENERATED ALWAYS.
  Hint: Use OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE to override.
```

Is there any way not to override *group_id* column and use postgres auto generated values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue by myself:

In my "test_dataset.dtd" i have described *group_id* column, therefore dbunit trying to insert *NULL* value when there is no explicit value in "test_data.xml". So if i delete *group_id* definition from the .dtd file, test data goes to postgres with *group_id* auto generated value.